Where can one find "the Puzzle benchmark" from Hennessy’s MIPS paper?
I'm reading Hennessy's original MIPS paper. At the end, it includes estimated performance using "The Puzzle benchmark". The reference for this reads:

Baskett, F., "Puzzle: an informal compute bound benchmark", Widely
circulated and run.

Well I'm sure it was widely circulated and run in 1982, but finding it today is proving a challenge. Does anyone have a pointer to the C source?

The C code is in this collection of benchmarks, starting line 488.
A Modula-2 version is at the end of this document.
It also looks like it was originally written in Pascal, so the Modula version may be closer to the original.
The full name of the author is Forrest Baskett.
All found using three Google searches, so not too challenging...

In case you're wondering what the "Gabriel benchmarks" are - of which PUZZLE is one - see Performance And Evaluation Of Lisp Systems (Gabriel, 1985) - PUZZLE is at pg 203 of the book.   In the acknowledgements he credits Baskett with PUZZLE.

I converted the C to use clock_gettime and get 2604 micros for Puzzle on my 11-year-old mac. The original MIPS was 6.5 seconds.
